# Trying to run rails app in Heroku I get PG:ERROR connection refused

Tags: postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

When I go to the default rails landing page there is no problem displaying it, but when I try to display the users I get the following message:

```
Started GET "/users" for 190.21.126.51 at 2013-03-27 03:27:19 +0000 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:  PG::Error (could not connect to server: Connection refused 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:   Is the server running on host "localhost" and accepting 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:   TCP/IP connections on port 5432? 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:  ): 
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1206:in `initialize' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1206:in `new' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1206:in `connect' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:329:in `initialize' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:309:in `new_connection' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:319:in `checkout_new_connection' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:241:in `block (2 levels) in checkout' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in `loop' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in `block in checkout' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:233:in `checkout' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:96:in `block in connection' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in `connection' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:404:in `retrieve_connection' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:168:in `retrieve_connection' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:142:in `connection' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:67:in `rescue in call' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:61:in `call' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__572927131951691028__call__675318756725154442__callbacks' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints app/web.1:    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread' 
Mar 26 20:27:19 timepoints heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path=/users host=timepoints.herokuapp.com fwd="190.21.126.51" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=8ms status=500 bytes=643 
Mar 26 20:27:20 timepoints heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=timepoints.herokuapp.com fwd="190.21.126.51" dyno=web.1 connect=20ms service=13ms status=304 bytes=0
```

I have set my `application.rb` and `production.rb` with:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

I did run `heroku run rake db:setup` as suggested in some other post, and also tried with `db:migrate` and `db:reset`

I have checked `heroku config` and I can see `DATABASE_URL` has been set the same as `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_OLIVE_URL`

I have also deleted the app and deployed to a new one, but the same problem keeps happening.

My `Gemfile` has the following:

```
group :production do
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'activerecord-postgresql-adapter'
end
```

I am using Rails 3.2.6 and Ruby 1.9.2

---

**UPDATE:**
I just upgraded to Rails 4.0.0 and Ruby 2.0.0, but I keep getting the same error

---

**UPDATE 2:**
I have downgraded my app to rails 3.1.0 and ruby 1.9.3 and that has taken care of some of the errors. I still have the problem of connecting to the server.

---

**UPDATE 3:**
I contacted Heroku and they helped me solved the problem. It was a connection to my development database I was calling in some helper file that was messing up the connection in production. Removing that SOLVED the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downgraded my app to rails 3.1.0 and ruby 1.9.3 and that has taken care of some of the errors.

Then I contacted Heroku and they helped me solved the problem. It was a connection to my development database I was calling in some helper file that was messing up the connection in production. Removing that SOLVED the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `gem 'pg'`

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

The connection should then be established automatically, assuming your `DATABASE_URL` is pointing to a valid database.

You should also confirm that `RAILS_ENV` (and maybe also `RACK_ENV`) are set to `production` in `$ heroku config`.

Does your Procfile mention either `RAILS_ENV` or `RACK_ENV`?

Comment: I have gem 'pg' outside group :production since I'm using postgresql for development and test. I dont seem to have a Procfile. All the vars I get when I run heroku config are DATABASE_URL, HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_OLIVE_URL and PAPERTRAIL_API_TOKEN.  How should I set the Rails_env or Rack_env? Thanks

Comment: ok, so I did heroku config:add RACK_ENV=production RAILS_ENV=production, but nothing changed

Comment: " gem 'activerecord-postgresql-adapter'" can be removed, unless you're manually establishing connections?

Comment: When removing that gem I get the following messages in the log:
Mar 27 10:02:06 myapp heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path=/ host=myapp.herokuapp.com fwd="190.21.126.51" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=6ms status=500 bytes=643 
Mar 27 10:02:07 myapp heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=myapp.herokuapp.com fwd="190.21.126.51" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=7ms status=500 bytes=643

Comment: that just tells you there was a 500 error. There should be other logs right after/before that to indicate the problem.

Comment: yes, sorry, I ran it again and I got more log messages. You can see them here: http://pastie.org/7140401

Comment: oh - please add "gem 'thin'" to your gem file (don't use webrick in production). Might not solve it but Webrick is threaded and isn't helping here.

Comment: thanks, I did add thin, but nothing changed. I did eliminate several of the log messages by downgrading to rails 3.1.0 and ruby 1.9.3. But I still have the PG:Error

Comment: Open a support ticket : https://help.heroku.com/tickets/new?query=pg+connection

Comment: I did, and they solved my problem! It was a connection to my development database I was calling in some helper file that was messing up the connection in production. Thanks for all your time and help.

Comment: I'm glad "they" were able to help :)